# Left mouse select in MATE-terminal stopped working!

Tags: terminal, clipboard, mate-terminal

I left town for a few weeks, but kept the desktop running, including many open terminals --  MATE-terminal v 1.24.1. Upon return, I found that left-mouse-button select (highlight-select, for cut-n-paste) stopped working ... for mate-terminal only!

Highlight-select works great in the the web browser, it works in xterm, it works in gnome-terminal. Just not in mate-terminal. (In other words, this shows that mouse kernel dev drivers and X11 seems to be working fine.) The time-stamps on `/usr/bin/mate-terminal` show that it was not updated while I was away... so I am stumped.

Comment: that sounds like a bug!

Answer (score 0):

And as I was writing the above question, it started working again!  I did `ls -la /usr/bin/*term*` to find anything that might be a terminal, and tried each one of them, to see if cut-n-paste worked. They did. The last one that I tried was `/usr/bin/uxterm` and after running that, left-mouse select started working (in already-open `mate-terminal`'s.)

I conclude: something in `uxterm` sets or clears or re-initializes some kind of state in the cut-n-paste buffers, unfreezing them from whatever frozen/invalid/hung state they were in.